# microcode update fail

Tags: kernel, drivers, firmware

I saw log:

```
microcode_ctl: kernel version "4.123456" failed early load check for "intel-06-4f-01", skipping
```

Does it mean, the microcode update will check kernel version?

We can find a similar log here (the issue is not related )

https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=69023

Answer (score 0):

I found the following on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/F10004/html/ol7-bug-28879995.html.

> During installation and while booting, an error may appear in the
>   system log:
>
> ```
> dracut:    microcode_ctl: kernel version "4.14.35-1818.3.3.el7uek.x86_64"
> failed early load check for "intel-06-4f-01", skipping
> ```
>
> The intel ucode 06-4f-01 file is incorrectly excluded from initramfs
>   for boot-time microcode updates on some kernel versions. This affects
>   certain Intel Xeon E5 v4 CPUs, one of the models formerly known as
>   Broadwell. Oracle Server X6-2 uses this CPU model. The message is
>   harmless provided the BIOS is current for any system using this
>   processor model, as the BIOS will perform the required update. This
>   issue is planned to be addressed in an errata update for
>   microcode_ctl. (Bug ID 28879995)